# Fast way to get size of very large folders

Tags: storage

I typically have to deal with folders (which contain subfolders) that are about 1 terabyte in size, and due to storage constraints, I need to remove folders often in order to stay within allotted capacity.

I have typically 30-40 folders, each containing up to about 13 subfolders.

Is there a FAST way to obtain the folder size?

I have tried `du -s .` from the parent folder but .. fast it is not.

grateful for help!

Comment: Approximate total number of files per top-level directory?

Comment: Approximate... means estimate myself?

Comment: Well, no-one here is going to be able to do it for you. I'm interested in knowing whether you've 10s, 1000s, or 1000000s of files in each directory tree.

Comment: Approximately how many **files** does that represent?

Comment: @ZakS roaima is interested in knowing an estimate of how big your individual directories are in terms of number of files, on average. Directories with huge number of files can sometimes be very difficult to work with (depending on the filesystem used).

Comment: @roaima between 90 and 500,000.  Sorry for the slow wits.  New but learning.

Comment: @drewbenn On average once every 3 weeks or so, and we delete what we need the least, holding onto what we think we need the most. (We recreate results if we made an error and destroyed records we still need).

Comment: @drewbenn you mean to plan for the crisis :) and just have a record in each folder of its size built up over time.  Yes.  Very rational and it would solve the problem. It is more labor intensive that I hoped but if that is the best way I may have to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the directory sizes are usually stable within a day, and it's important to quickly get the size information at some point during the day, the best method for you would be an *automated* job to gather the information ahead of time. If your user has the required read access, it could be as simple as putting this one line inside your own crontab (`crontab -e`) to run nightly at 2:30 am:

```
30 2 * * * ( date ; du --summarize path1 path2 ; date ) >> $HOME/du_out.txt
```

As you get more confident with the results you can extend it into a script, perhaps running in a system-wide cron capacity so other administrators can maintain it, and add information about creation or access dates to *automatically delete* the oldest and largest files if available space is too low (presumably you already have a mechanism so important directories that should be kept longer are "promoted" to another location).

Of course if you already have a comprehensive build system, like jenkins, forget everything I said about cron and create this as a job there.

Answer (score -1):

We can try with below command it will show which parent folder occupying most of spaces

```
for i in parentfolder1 parentfolder2 parentfolder3
do
find $i -printf "%s %p\n"|awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$1}END{print sum}';echo $i; done| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| sort -k1 -nr| sed -n '1p'
```